# wxWidgets how to cross compile an application for windows from linux using codeblocks?

Tags: ubuntu, mingw, wxwidgets, codeblocks, wine

I would like to cross compile a wxWidgets application for windows from Linux using the codeblocks IDE.

I have read through [these](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Cross-Compiling_Under_Linux) instructions which provide some useful information, but the instructions do not cover codeblocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the steps I followed on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)

Update the system and install mingw32 and wine:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mingw32 wine
```

Install wxWidgets 2.8 from source:

```
sudo su -
cd /opt
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wxwindows/2.8.12/wxWidgets-2.8.12.tar.gz
tar -xvzf wxWidgets-2.8.12.tar.gz
cd wxWidgets-2.8.12/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/i586-mingw32 --host=i586-mingw32msvc --build=i686-linux --disable-shared --enable-unicode
make
make install
```

Install codeblocks

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks codeblocks-contrib
```

Open codeblocks, then setup as follows:

```
Settings > Compiler > 

   Selected Compiler > GNU GCC Compiler > Copy > New Compiler Name : MinGW Compiler

   Selected Compiler > MinGW Compiler

   Search Directories > Compiler > Add : /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/
   Search Directories > Linker > Add : /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/
   Search Directories > Resource Compiler > Add : /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/

   Toolchain Executables >
       Program Files >
           Compilers Installation Directory : /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/
           C Compiler : i586-mingw32msvc-gcc
           C++ Compiler : i586-mingw32msvc-g++
           Dynamic Linker : i586-mingw32msvc-g++
           Static Linker : i586-mingw32msvc-ld
      Additional Paths : /usr/bin

Compiler Settings >  Other Options : `/usr/local/i586-mingw32/bin/wx-config --cxxflags` 
Linker Settings > Other Options : `/usr/local/i586-mingw32/bin/wx-config --libs`
```

Now create a new project in codeblocks, the key fields are as follows:

```
New Project > wXWidgets Project
    wXWidgets > 2.8.x
    Preferred GUI Builder > wxSmith
    Compiler > MinGW Compiler
```

In Codeblocks, click on compile - this sets up the applications output folder which we need in the next step.

In a terminal window, copy required `mingwm10.dll` to output folder:

```
cd <your applications Debug folder>
cp /usr/share/doc/mingw32-runtime/mingwm10.dll.gz .
gunzip mingwm10.dll.gz
```

Now run with wine:

```
wine ./youappname
```

To run your application on windows machine, copy `mingwm10.dll` and your appname executable to a windows machine.  Rename your appname to have the suffix .exe.  Double click to run.