# Cross-compiling with wxwidgets in codeblocks

Tags: linux, wxwidgets, codeblocks, cross-compiling, mingw32

I searched around a fair amount and didn't see anyone else with this specific problem. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (amd64) and codeblocks 13.12 (from the ubuntu repositories). I've followed the directions here: "[wxWidgets how to cross compile an application for windows from linux using codeblocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396669/wxwidgets-how-to-cross-compile-an-application-for-windows-from-linux-using-codeb)" and am finding myself a bit stuck. I can successfully compile win32 CLI code and code that uses windows.h. If I create a wxwidgets project I can successfully compile it for linux, but if I try and compile it using the mingw compiler setup (per the instructions in that link) I get the following error:

```
unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-local-typedefs"
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this option, you're using a compiler too old to have it. As all `-Wno-xxx` options, this one just suppresses a warning, so removing it is harmless.